# Adding a date to my title page given my current usepackage set

Tags: formatting, titles, apa-style, syntax

Very new user of LaTeX here making my first ever document using this typeset. I'm just about done, but am running into a really annoying issue with incorporating a course name and date on my title page. Heres my title page code:

```
        \documentclass[man]{apa7}
    
    
    
    \usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
    
    \usepackage[american]{babel}
    
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    
    \usepackage{float}
    
    \restylefloat{table}
    
    \usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
    
    \usepackage{textgreek}
    
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    
    \usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
    
    \addbibresource{references.bib}




\title{PAPER TITLE}

\shorttitle{RUNNING HEAD}



\author{AUTHORS}

\affiliation{AFFILIATION}

\setlength\intextsep{1mm}

\begin{document}

TEXT

\end{document}
```

Any time I try to add \date or \text{today's date} it either doesnt show up or will  show up in the top right corner above my name and affiliation. I want a course name and date to appear below my name and affiliation as per apa 7 guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{
\@ifundefined{hrm}{}{\hrm}
 \check@author
 
  \begin{center}


  \vspace*{4\baselineskip}
  \textbf\@title%
  \ifapamodeman{%
    \@ifundefined{def@noextraspace}{%
      \vspace{\baselineskip}\\
    }{\\}
  }{%
    \vspace{\baselineskip}\\
  }
\@ifundefined{def@stu}{ %Professional manuscript
  \@ifundefined{apaSeven@maskauthoridentity}{%  BDB

      \displayauthors \\
      \displayaffiliations
      \@ifundefined{@coursename}
       {\vspace*{\baselineskip}}
       {\@coursename}
       
       \@date

      \@ifundefined{@note}
       {\vspace*{\baselineskip} }
       {\@note}

  }{%  mask author identity -- show nothing in the author or author note space
  }

  \end{center}

  \@ifundefined{apaSeven@maskauthoridentity}{
      \@ifundefined{@acks}
       {}
       {%
         \vfill%
        \section{\normalfont\normalsize\textbf\acksname}
         \raggedright
         \setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
         \indent\@acks\par%
       }
  }{%  mask author identity -- show nothing in the author or author note space
  }}{% Student Manuscript
      \displayauthors \\

      \displayaffiliations

      \@course \\
      \@professor \\
      \@duedate \\

      \@ifundefined{@note}
       {\vspace*{\baselineskip} }
       {\@note}

        \end{center}

       \@ifundefined{@acks}
       {}
       {%
         \vfill%
        \section{\normalfont\normalsize\textbf\acksname}
         \raggedright
         \setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
         \indent\@acks\par%
       }

  }
  \newpage
  %BDB\hyphenpenalty 10000
  \fussy
  \@ifundefined{@abstract}{}{%
    \section{\normalfont\normalsize\textbf\abstractname}% BDB
    \noindent\@abstract\par% BDB
    \@ifundefined{@keywords}{}{%
      \setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}% BDB
      \indent\textit{\keywordname:} \@keywords%
    }%
    \newpage
  }

  \@ifundefined{def@donotrepeattitle}{
    \section{\protect\normalfont\textbf{\@title}}
  }{}%
  \raggedright%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}%
}
\long\def\coursename#1{\long\def\@coursename{#1}}
\makeatother

\title{PAPER TITLE}
\shorttitle{RUNNING HEAD}
\coursename{THE COURSE}%<--Here you can change the name of the course
\author{AUTHORS}
\affiliation{AFFILIATION}

\setlength\intextsep{1mm}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

TEXT
\end{document}
```

[image: Title page]

[image: Second page]

If you want to change something, let me know.